# How to add string values from multiple columns in List<string> c# windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I'm trying to create List of strings from a SQL Server database table.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCountry_GetCountryDataById]
    @CountryId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        CountryName, Continent, Population, Capital, 
        Language, Religion, Currency, DishName 
    FROM
        Country 
    WHERE 
        id = @CountryId
END
```

And this is my method for query:

```
public static List<string> GetCountryDataByCountryId(int countryId)
{
    List<string> countryData = new List<string>();

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CnnString("MathemaKids")))
    {
        DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("CountryId", countryId);

        countryData = connection.Query<string>("spCountry_GetCountryDataById", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    }

    return countryData;
}
```

So, I'm expecting 8 strings in my list, but when I run this it returns only first string (`CountryName`).

Where is the problem, anyone?

Comment: You should create a data class that corresponds to country table fields, and have a List of this class on your Query and result

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that corresponds- maps to your table structure. Try, like:

```
public class Country
{
  //I have defined all as strings, better to define them corresponding to your table datatypes
  public string CountryName {get;set;}
  public string Continent {get;set;}
  public string Population {get;set;}
  public string Capital {get;set;} 
  public string Language {get;set;}
  public string Religion {get;set;}
  public string Currency {get;set;}
  public string DishName {get;set;}
}

public static List<Country> GetCountryDataByCountryId(int countryId)
{
   List<Country> countryData = new List<Country>();
   using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CnnString("MathemaKids")))
   {
       DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
       p.Add("CountryId", countryId);
        countryData = connection.Query<string>("spCountry_GetCountryDataById", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    }
   return countryData;
}
```

Comment: Why is `population` a string?? This most likely will be a **numerical** value - so you should really **not** just use a string - use the appropriate datatype (like `int`) instead!

Comment: I have added comment in the start of the class

Comment: Surely you need `connection.Query<Country>` not `connection.Query<string>`?

Comment: I've not used dapper but is `connection.Query<string>` correct? Would of guessed it should be `connection.Query<Country>`.